# How to use two different plugins on one type of file in SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I want to apply **sonar text plugin** and **sonar jproperties plugin** to scan properties/txt/sh/xml files via regular expressions, but received such error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.1.1:sonar (default-cli) on project test: Language of file 'src/main/java/test.properties' can not be decided as the file matches patterns of both  sonar.lang.patterns.jproperties : **/*.properties and sonar.lang.patterns.text : **/*.properties,**/*.txt -> [Help 1]
```

How to avoid this problem and fix limitation of sonar?

Answer (score 2):

You're stuck.

To make a plugin check a file type, typically you would configure it to "claim" that file extension (**Administration > General Settings > [language] > General > File suffixes**). But each file extension can be claimed/declared by one, and only one plugin. Presumably in your attempts to make this work, you've configured both plugins to claim the `.xml` file extension. Hence the error you're seeing.

Short of some custom development on your part, you're not going to get this to work.

On the topic of custom development, it's worth noting that the Java plugin does check some `.xml` files without claiming/declaring that file extension. So if you go this route, you probably want to take a look at how the Java plugin gets this done.

But because files with unclaimed extensions are by default not indexed (and therefore not checkable) these Java plugin rules only work when either

- the XML plugin is installed to declare the `.xml` file extension and have those filed indexed and therefore available to the rules
- **Administration > General > Analysis Scope > Files > Import unknown files** is set to `true`. (It defaults to `false`.)

**UPDATE**

Changes to the way the scanner works means that even files with unclaimed extensions are now indexed if an analyzer raises an issue on them. So, e.g. you  no longer need SonarXML installed before SonarJava can raise issues on pom.xml files.

Comment: This restriction prevents our team from using the 'coverity-sonar-plugin-1.6.2.jar' to integrate with Coverity, as it wants to claim the C/C++ extensions, while we still need the SonarQube's C/C++ processor to do its job.  Importing the Coverity issues is just to add to the copus of data, not to replace what we are already collecting through SonarQube.

Comment: @simon.watts if you're already analyzing C/C++ then the Coverity plugin shouldn't need to declare the extension. And there's never a question of "replacing". Just configure the Coverity plugin to not claim the extension if you can.

Comment: Sonar should support two plugins to claim the same "file extensions": one plugin have X rules implemented, and the other add Y rules. It sounds like a limitation of SonarQube.